# Which devices and iOS versions do support iAP2?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, settings

Is there any information available about; which devices and which versions of iOS do support iAP2? ([iPod Accessory Protocol 2 - 7th Chapter](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf))

Is this information available on the phone? Can you somehow look it up, if the phone supports iAP2?

I would like to test some of the features of this new version.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical specification for iAP2 is only available to the members of the [MFi licensing program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

This information can't be found on the phone. Most of the devices with up-to-date iOS version should support the protocol, but the actual list and technical details are only available for the members of the MFi licensing program.